# Android get bps from audio sample

Tags: android

I would like to make an android application that opens the device microphone and records same samples, my question is if it is possible to know the bps(bits per second) of the recorded audio file. Also is this possible to do from a file stores on the sd card?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but bits per second = bits per sample * sample rate, which may be easier to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AudioRecord is the class to read up on....  you specify the sample size and sample rate, it gives you an error if it doesnt like what you asked for.

Comment: In AudioRecord I specify the actual sample siza and bit rate so isn't this mean that everything I record has the same bps?